# As a user on a VPN how do I control which server a DNS request goes to

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, vpn, dns

I work from home using a Windows 10 machine. It's connected to the company network using Forticlient SSL VPN. This uses split tunneling so only certain traffic is routed over the VPN. However, it sets my DNS server to point to the company's DNS servers. I have several dev servers locally that I stop being able to resolve when that change happens. Also, their DNS is super slow and I'd prefer to use my own DNS in general except when looking up certain domains (company related ie: company.domain). Ideally I'd like some sort of local dns client that looks at the request and then sends it to specific dns servers based on the domain name. So on my system the DNS server probably becomes 127.0.0.1. Requests for company.domain get sent to company dns server. The lookup for google.com would go to my.dns. The lookup for internal.server would go to my.dns as well.

EDIT:
Really want I want to be able to do is intercept the DNS request and say oh, that's for a company domain use this server to look it up or, oh this isn't company domain use this server to look it up.

Comment: I don't  really understand (yes, I use VPN).  The IP address and DNS at your end is from your ISP. The IP address and DNS at the company end are from the company's ISP.  What else do you need?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You should contact your system administrator for assistance.

Comment: @John, the dns server after connecting to the VPN changes to the company's AD dns so that internal services can be lookedup.

Comment: That is up to the company so far as I know. They set up the VPN

Comment: @Ramhound my question is how do I control which server is used based on the hostname of the request.

Comment: @John Yes, they set up the vpn but they don't have split DNS setup so all my DNS requests are being processed by them. I'm looking for a way to control that on my end so that only specific requests go to their servers.

Comment: You said they set it up as Split Tunnel (some traffic goes VPN and some goes outside). The DNS servers used outside may be different than inside. Normal. At least so far as I can see.

Comment: @john Their DNS server is an internal ip so it's traffic goes down the tunnel but even if it didn't it wouldn't really matter. At the end of the day the only thing I want to see tem resolve is stuff related to the AD. Internet facing stuff I want to lookup with my own dns server. Really want I want to be able to do is intercept the DNS request and say oh, that's for a company domain use this server to look it up or, oh this isn't company domain use this server to look it up.

Comment: You need to ask company IT how you will intercept DNS requests and probably they will want to know why.

Comment: @john I think you are misunderstanding, the request originates from my personal system. I should be able to look at it BEFORE it leaves my system and tell it where to go. If I was able to say go to "MY IP" then it would never be resolved by my company.

Comment: I don’t think I misunderstand VPN but I am not clear on what you are trying to do except hide your system from them . Given it is their VPN I don’t know how you can accomplish what you want

Comment: Can you simply use the hosts file to perform the necessary work for your intranet websites? Once you connect to the VPN you won’t be able to not use your company’s DNS server.

Comment: Are you actually able to reconfigure DNS settings once connected to your company VPN to a point that you can resolve hostnames with a 3rd party DNS server?

Comment: I don't want to hide my system from them I just dont want EVERY SINGLE dns request to use the VPN. I only want certain dns requests to go over the tunnel. Since I  CAN change my DNS server to w/e I want I can make it so that NO names are looked up over the tunnel.. but then I can't resolve company names.

Comment: @Scottmeup yup, no restrictions there. my own system on my own domain in my own environment.

Comment: Can you disconnect when you do not need to be connected and then your other work will not go down the tunnel.  So perhaps split your time (and connection) between your work and their work.

Comment: Yes but the resolution takes forever. Almost had me carving my brain out today. Was hoping to just cut them out of most requests :P

Comment: I'd look into seeing if rolling your own DNS server with a global nameserver for public hostnames and your company nameserver for company hostnames would achieve your goal. You can find nameservers in linux using `dig +short ns foo.bar` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I was able to find was a 3rd party solution: https://yogadns.com/

It intercepts dns requests and sends them to a DNS pool based on rules you create.

To solve my situation I created a pool to contain my work's DNS servers and pool to contain my own DNS servers (you could put 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 or w/e here).
Then I created a rule, put it at the top and entered the following settings:

- Hostname:  *.company.domain;*.other.companydomain
- Action:  "Process via Ethernet 4". For me this interface comes up when I connect to the vpn and goes down when I disconnect. open ncpa.cpl and see what comes up for you.
- DNS Server: the pool I created for them
- Click Ok and then make sure "Ignore this rule when its network interface is down" is ticked. This is really important if you need to resolve DNS to connect to the VPN or perform MFA.

Now, change the Default rule to use the pool you created for yourself and set the Action to Process.

Comment: Pretty good solution, worked very well for my case. I'll see if it can route traffic properly between two open vpn connections and if it does, this will be an instant buy.